# How to get Discussion Item URL using client object model?

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I have a discussion board. Using client object model, I can create a new thread:

```
List lst = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Test");

//Create the topic
ListItem t = Utility.CreateNewDiscussion(ctx, lst, templateSubject);
t["Body"] = templateBody;

t.Update();
```

But, how can I get the new thread's url? Query the list again? which field I should load?

Comment: Are you tryin to reply to created discussion item?

Comment: no, I try to get the url of the discussion thread. so I can send it to someone else to check the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListItem["FileRef"]` returns server relative url of list item, in case of Discussion item the format is as follows:

```
/Lists/Discussion/<Topic title>
```

Example:

```
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Discussion");
var t = Utility.CreateNewDiscussion(ctx, list, templateSubject);
t["Body"] = templateBody;
t.Update();
ctx.Load(t);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
var topicAbsUrl = ctx.Url + t["FileRef"];  //get absolute url
```